# Como criar gráfico no RStudio com ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Preciso criar um gráfico de barras simples com dados de um data frame.
Mas quero dividir cada barra do gráfico em três.

Por exemplo:
Na barra referente o ano de 2000, tenho que colocar três valores diferentes. 
Isso deve ser repetido até o ano de 2015.
Logo seis barras, sendo que cada uma deve ser dividida em três para colocar valores diferentes.

Estava usando

```
ggplot(data =  ) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x , fill ), position = "dodge")
```

este código, mas não consigo montar o data frame que seja lido pela função.

Quero um gráfico conforme o da imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `ggplot(data =  diamonds, mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = color)) + geom_bar(position = "dodge")`.